# How to get all users using FosUserBundle?

Tags: symfony

I am using symfony2 and FosUserBundle as a user manager. I want to display all users. I have tried the code below but it returns a blank page.

How can I fix it?

controller :

```
<?php

namespace Annuaire\AdminBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class AdminController extends Controller {

    public function indexAction() {
        return $this->render('AnnuaireAdminBundle:Admin:index.html.twig');
    }

    //get all users
    public function usersAction() {
        //access user manager services 

        $userManager = $container->get('fos_user.user_manager');
        $users = $userManager->findUsers();

        return $this->render('AnnuaireAdminBundle:Admin:users.html.twig', array('users' =>   $users));
    }

}
```

twig :

```
<h1>get all users</h1>
{% for user in users %}
<li>{{ user.username|e }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Completely blank?  Not even showing the "get all users" heading?

Comment: it is completly blank and when i remove this $userManager = $container->get('fos_user.user_manager');
        $users = $userManager->findUsers(); it displays "get all users"

Comment: Probably running in production mode.  Make sure you are in development so you can see the error messages.

Comment: am in the developing mode

Comment: add error_reporting(E_ALL); to app_dev.php.  Based on what you have posted, the routing is getting to the action and the template is being called.  An exception/error is being thrown some where and is being suppressed.

Comment: how to add error_reporting(E_ALL); to app_dev.php file?

Comment: Open up web/app_dev.php in an editor and add the line to it at the top of the file.  It just turns on all error reporting.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Silly me.  This:

```
$userManager = $container->get('fos_user.user_manager');
```

Should be:

```
$userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');
```

You will still want to get your error reporting turned on for your application.  This should have tossed an "unknown variable" error message and would have been trivial to track down.